# How to implement leaderboard using StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

currently I'm using StreamBuilder for my Leaderboard. But this will show all the documents or the number of documents I will initially set. Let's say I have a Leaderboard of top 100 documents. If the account is in the top 100 documents, then no problem. But if it is not included in the top 100 documents, I wanted to show first the top 100 documents, then account the user has. Here's the sample of how I wanted to show if the user account is beyond 100.

[image: sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following in your stream builder

```
 CollectionReference collections = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Collections').limit(100);
```

Try using stream builder with limit function other wise add more information or code to get help faster and also rich for more people